# Find files starting with NULs

Tags: grep, find

How do I efficiently find all the files in the system whose contents starts with \x0000000000 (5 NUL bytes)?
Tried to do the following

```
$ find . -type f -exec grep -m 1 -ovP "[^\x00]" {} 
$ find . -type f -exec grep -m 1 -vP "^\00{5}" {}
```

but the first variant works only for all-NUL files, and the last one searches through the whole file, not only the first 5 bytes, which makes it very slow and gives many false positives.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
grep -r '^\\x0000000000' * | cut -d ":" -f 1
```